# Datatables -Load JSON data into a table

Tags: jquery, json, api, datatables

I am using datatables and I have data coming form an API, how can I populate my table? Response is in JSON key pair format

```
{
    "site": "SITE A",
    "sent": "141558",
    "open": "470",
    "click": "0",
    "delivered": "0",
},
{
        "site": "SITE B",
        "sent": "141558",
        "open": "470",
        "click": "0",
        "delivered": "0",
    },
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="table datatable-basic table-bordered table-striped table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:center;">
  <thead style="text-align:center;background-color:#BE1E2D; color:white">
                       <tr>
                                <th>Site Visited</th>
                                <th>Sent</th>
                                <th>Open</th>
                                <th>Clicked</th>
                                <th>Delivered</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#getData').on('click', function () {

        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": 'http://localhost/API/index.php'
        } );
    });
```

Comment: Show us where/how you're using datatables.

Comment: Are you getting the JSON via ajax?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this JSON via ajax

Comment: @IsaacKleinman see my edit for `Datatables`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `columns` property if you get an array of objects from the api, also if it's a post request you should specify that too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
             "url": "http://localhost/API/index.php",
             "type": "POST"
         },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "site" },
            { "data": "sent" },
            { "data": "open" },
            { "data": "click" },
            { "data": "delivered" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: it is get, changed that to `GET` but still seeing the same error

Comment: This error means that the expected data from the server is not a valid json, use your developer tool to see what the server send

Comment: Also make sure that the data returned from the server is an array of objects: `[{},{}...]`

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript to look like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "http://localhost/API/index.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "site" },
            { "data": "sent" },
            { "data": "open" },
            { "data": "click" },
            { "data": "delivered" }           
        ]
    } );
```